# Date Time Picker Culture info in Window Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

My system language is Arabic, if I add `DateTimePicker` control on window form it shows Arabic months, and dates. I want to display it as English, so far I tried below methods but it is not working. Calendar control still show Arabic.

Value from DTP is saved as English format, but issue is the view of calendar control.

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
dtpBTStartDate.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dtpBTStartDate.CustomFormat = Application.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern;
```

I tried to add thread method in Program.cs and also on form's Load , but still not working. Please advise?

Comment: If the OS UI language is Arabic I believe all `DateTimePicker` and `MonthCalendar` controls will be shown with arabic UI, because those controls are just a wrapper around `SysDateTimePick32` and `SysMonthCal32`.

Comment: As an alternative you can use the open source FarsiLibrary. While the library is called FarsiLibrary but its `DateTimePicker` and `MonthView` controls supports Jalali (Shamsi/Persian), Hijri (Qamari) and Gregorian calendars. Here is the link for [codeproject article](http://seesharpsoftware.com.au/farsilibrary-v2.6-now-available/), [page of the library](http://seesharpsoftware.com.au/farsilibrary-v2.6-now-available/) in the author's site and the [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Farsi.Library/) package.

Comment: Thank you will check that. I guess we cannot change the UI of calendar if System Language is Arabic, but we can change the date when selected in control, if i use above code with `dtpBTStartDate.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";` it will give date and month ok, but year is still of Hijri.

Comment: [How to Localize Windows Forms and Change the Language at Runtime](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=174)

Comment: We had to use Telerik Controls to resolve this issue, they support Culture property for datetimepicker. For default datetimepicker win form controls even if i use thread method it dont work. If i add custom format it will still show Arabic calendar and only convert value to custom format. Saving data is easy using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. But this issue was related to UI of control. Yes one more thing there is Farsi Library mentioned by @RezaAghaei available which is free and can be used as well, in case if someone dont have Telerik license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:** If the OS UI language is Arabic I believe all `DateTimePicker` and `MonthCalendar` controls will be shown with Arabic UI, because those controls are just a wrapper around `SysDateTimePick32` and `SysMonthCal32`.

**Note:** As an alternative you can use 3rd party libraries. The free open source FarsiLibrary is an option. While the library is called FarsiLibrary but its DateTimePicker and MonthView controls supports Jalali (Shamsi/Persian), Hijri (Qamari) and Gregorian calendars. Here is the link for [codeproject article](http://seesharpsoftware.com.au/farsilibrary-v2.6-now-available/), [page of the library](http://seesharpsoftware.com.au/farsilibrary-v2.6-now-available/) in the author's site and the [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Farsi.Library/).

Comment: I prefer not to change UI of the control and let the user decide about UI using its OS. The UI is just an interface to select the date time. Then the selected date is a DateTime. You can calculate the date in different cultures using the selected date if you need.